# newbie oracle update statement error

Tags: sql, oracle

oracle query:

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY 
SET CASES_PRODUCED = (SELECT DISTINCT PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY
                       FROM AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY, HISTORY_PRODUCTION, PERIOD_TO_PROCESS
                      WHERE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM 
                        AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM 
                        AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY.LOC_ID = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.LOC_ID 
                        AND HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM 
                        AND HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM);
```

is returning the following error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Another attempt at correction:

```
 MERGE INTO AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY1 
  USING (SELECT DISTINCT PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY, 
           AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY2.rowid AS r 
      FROM AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY2 
           INNER JOIN HISTORY_PRODUCTION 
              ON AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY2.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM 
                 AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY2.FSCL_YR_NUM = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM 
                 AND AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY2.LOC_ID = HISTORY_PRODUCTION.LOC_ID 
           INNER JOIN PERIOD_TO_PROCESS 
              ON HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_WK_IN_YR_NUM 
                 AND HISTORY_PRODUCTION.FSCL_YR_NUM = PERIOD_TO_PROCESS.FSCL_YR_NUM) 
   ON (AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY1.rowid = r) 
 WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE 
  SET CASES_PRODUCED = PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY;
```

returns the following error:

> ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

I am a noob and need help :(

thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign only a single, scalar value to CASES_PRODUCED. So your subquery needs to produce only a single, scalar value.

You need to find why your subquery returns more than one row.

`SELECT DISTINCT ...` will select unique rows, not the same as `ONE ROW`.

Do you need the sum total of all the PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY in the rows?

Or the average?

Or the MAX number?

Or the first row?

Use an aggregate function if so:

Total

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY 
    SET CASES_PRODUCED = (SELECT SUM(PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY) ...
```

Max

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY 
    SET CASES_PRODUCED = (SELECT MAX(PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY) ...
```

Average

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY 
    SET CASES_PRODUCED = (SELECT AVG(PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY) ...
```

First row

```
UPDATE AIRMODEL_NETWORK_SUMMARY 
    SET CASES_PRODUCED = (SELECT PRDCTN_RUN_ACTL_CASE_QTY ... 
                          FROM ... 
                          WHERE ROWNUM = 1)
```

It is critical, especially when learning, and struggling with syntax, that you clearly understand

1. What you need from the query
2. What your query is returning

Just trying a bunch of alternatives until you get success is a sure fire way to create erroneous data that seems to work.

My suggestion is to first copy the subquery `SELECT` to a different window and run it, view and understand the results. It should be clear that it is a multi-row result. Work with the subquery until it is returning a correct, single result, then plug it back into the larger update.

Comment: I am trying to update the column in airmodel_network_summary with the values in the select when they meet the conditions.